# apache access and error log written in same file

Tags: apache-2.2

i have issue that access and error log are written in same file ! , the configuration in virtualhosts.conf as the following :

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  ************
  ServerAdmin support@************8
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/*********.com
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/********/********.com_error_log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/********/********.com_access_log combined
  <Directory /var/www/html/***********.com>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

as you see from the configuration each access and error logs should be save separately , but both logs are written in *.com_access_log , i have double check all permission , group and owner ... can't find anything wrong

previous error in log file :

```
[Thu Sep 19 14:15:02 2013] [error] [client 192.168.10.54] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/**********/show_has_offers.php
```

i have tried to generate same error , i can find the hit in access log only as the following :

```
192.168.10.75 - - [24/Oct/2013:08:11:14 +0000] "GET /show_has_offers.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1586 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0" 0 17332
```

and nothing in error log !!

Please advice ...

Comment: Can you give an example of what kind of errors you're seeing in the access log, that shouldn't be there? I'm thinking that you're maybe misunderstanding what an http error log usually contains. 404 etc is not an error for the server..

Answer (score 0):

Your example in the comments above was:

> 192.168.10.125 - - [15/Aug/2013:14:11:55 +0000] "POST /check-status/ HTTP/1.1" 400 117 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UN AVAILABLE (java 1.4)" 0
>   23314

First of all: /check-status is a special URL alias that Apache uses for querying mod_status. It's normally not an alias you enable on a VirtualHost.

That is not a server-side error per say. It's a http request made by an client, which the server responded 400 to (malformed request). Set the `Loglevel` directive to `info` or `debug` to see if you can get detailed info about it.

The standard way of doing this is to get apache to only log actual *errors* to the error log. Writing an error in the error log every single time a client creates a malformed request or a file is missing (404) defeats the point of having an error log that you carefully watch.